# What is the recommended workflow for vue.js + i18n?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n, django-i18n

I have recently made the jump from developing using the Django framework to vue.js. One thing I am having a hard time wrapping my head around is the workflow for adding translations.

In Django, my workflow felt very intuitive:

1. Annotate my code with translation hooks.
2. Pull out the translation hooks into a .po (gettext) file
3. Translate the messages into the desired locale, i.e. do work in the .po file
4. Compile the .po file

In the context where all of my work needs to be translated, this workflow was very convenient and fool-proof.

I am excited about the move over to vue.js but I am afraid the difference in translation workflow might be a deal-breaker. Or perhaps, there is something I am missing? Here is my understanding of the vue.js/i18n workflow

1. Annotate my code with translation hooks. Unlike the Django process, I am using a Translation ID to link messages and translations.
2. **Manually** add those translation ids to a JSON file, e.g. `en.json`
3. Mirror that json file to that of a different locale, e.g., `fr.json`

I understand that I can use a tool like [BabelEdit](https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/download) to manage the last step. While this seems like a great tool, it is the second step that I am really having a hard time getting my head around. Without a function like the django-admin/gettext `makemessages` this seems like it would be a tedious and inefficient task.

What am I getting wrong here? I imagine I am not the only one with these needs, so what are the translation workflows that are working for others developing with vue.js?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use https://github.com/pixari/vue-i18n-extract on step 2. I think that BabelEdit can only help if you keep your translations as `<i18n>` section in your Vue components (in which case you will need https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-loader)